# Change Color of Shape Mid Tween

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs, tweenjs

I'm trying to make an event that changes my shapes stroke color for 5 seconds when a button is clicked, and then the shape returns to original color after the duration.

I am able to do this with clearing the entire stage and redrawing new shapes (which resets their position), but I can't figure it out with the current shapes.

**Q.** What's the best way to approach making a change to a shapes color, during a Tween?

I was also curious if there's a better way to handling tweening the shapes width?  Currently I am relying on ScaleX and ScaleY - but this also changes the stroke's size - which is not desired.

**[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4qznqa6/7/)**

**HTML**

```
<button id="change">Click to Change Color</button>
<canvas id="demoCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
var stage,
        circle;

function init() {
  stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
  createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}

function createCircle(){
  circle = new createjs.Shape().set({name:"circle"});
  circle.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1).beginStroke("#000").beginFill( "#FFF" ).drawCircle(0, 0, 20);
  circle.x = 100;
  circle.y = 100;

  stage.addChild(circle);

  createjs.Tween.get(circle, {loop: true})
    .to({x: 225, y: 225}, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(1))
    .to({x: 100, y: 100}, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(1));

  circle2 = new createjs.Shape().set({name:"circle"});
  circle2.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1).beginStroke("#000").beginFill( "#FFF" ).drawCircle(0, 0, 20);
  circle2.x = 400;
  circle2.y = 400;

  stage.addChild(circle2);

  createjs.Tween.get(circle2, {loop: true})
    .to({scaleX: 2, scaleY: 2, x: 425, y: 125}, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(1))
    .to({scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1, x: 400, y: 400}, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(1));

  stage.update();
}

$( "#change" ).click(function() {
  // change color
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  init();
  createCircle();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few questions in this post, so I will try to answer them all:

First, a solution to most of your issues is Graphic commands. Commands provide a simple way to store graphic instructions, and change them later. Here is a simple example:

```
var shape = new createjs.Shape();
var colorCmd = shape.graphics.beginFill("red").command;
var rectCmd = shape.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100).command;
// Later
colorCmd.style = "blue";
rectCmd.w = 200;
stage.update(); // Remember to update the stage after changing properties
```

You can read more about commands on the [createjs blog](http://blog.createjs.com/new-command-approach-to-easeljs-graphics/). All commands and their properties are documented in the [EaselJS docs](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.Fill.html).

---

1. **Change a color:** I outlined this in the example above, but the short answer is to adjust the `style` property of a fill command. If you want to change it instantly, you can just set up a `Tween.call`:

Example:

```
createjs.Tween.get(circle, {loop: true})
    .to({x: 225, y: 225}, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(1))
    .call(function(tween) {
        colorCmd.style = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)"; // Change to 50% blue
    })
    .to({x: 100, y: 100}, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(1));
```

If you want to *tween* the color, then you could check out the ColorPlugin, which is currently in a "Plugins" branch of TweenJS: https://github.com/CreateJS/TweenJS/tree/Plugins/extras/plugins

```
// Tween the color from its current value to blue.
// Note that only hex, short hex, HSL, and RGB formats are supported.
createjs.Tween.get(colorCmd).to({style:"#0000ff"});
```

2. **Change the size**: The example above also shows how to modify the values of a `drawRect` call. You can do the same with any other draw command (including moveTo, lineTo, polyStar, etc).

Scaling also works, and if you want to not scale the stroke, just set the `ignoreScale` parameter on the [stroke style](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#method_setStrokeStyle).

```
shape.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1, null, null, null, true);
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to write all of this out, and when I read everything - it made sense. However, when I tried it out, I couldn't get it to work properly. Perhaps I'm missing something here?  

Would I use `.style` for stroke and drop shadow of shapes as well?

http://jsfiddle.net/m4qznqa6/9/

Comment: Ah, I see I was referencing it incorrectly.  If the shape had a shadow applied to it, would this be a similar process? The only issue I have is with strokes drawing twice (do I need to clear them somehow) and not sure how to apply a drop/box shadow in the same way.  http://jsfiddle.net/m4qznqa6/14/