# Createjs, how to use the mouse to draw a rectangle in the stage

Tags: createjs

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PShA.jpg)
I want to  use the mouse to draw a rectangle on the stage,but the rect can't change size.

this is code:

```
var planetText,selectBox=new createjs.Shape(),x, y, width, height;
  stage.on('mousedown',function(event){
    x = event.stageX;y = event.stageY;
    selectBox.graphics.beginFill('#ffffff').drawRect(x, y, 100, 100);
    selectBox.set({alpha:0.5});
    planetText = new createjs.Text(x+','+y +','+0+','+0, "16px Arial", "#ffffff");
    planetText.set({textAlign:'center',textBaseline:'middle',x:x,y:y});

    //console.log(selectBox);
    stage.addChild(selectBox);
    stage.addChild(planetText);
    stage.update();

  });
  stage.addEventListener('pressmove',function (event){
    //console.log(event);
    width = event.stageX - x;
    height = event.stageY - y;
    planetText.text = x + ',' + y +','+width+','+height;
    //selectBox.set({w:width,h:height});
    createjs.Tween.get(selectBox).to({width:width,height:height},100,createjs.Ease.bounceIn());
    stage.update();
  });
  stage.on('pressup',function(event){
    //console.log(self.selectBox);
    createjs.Tween.get(selectBox).to({alpha:0},300,createjs.Ease.bounceIn());
    stage.removeChild(selectBox);
    stage.update();
  });
```

how to fixed it , thx~

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question/answer:
[Change Color of Shape Mid Tween](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877474/change-color-of-shape-mid-tween/36895027#36895027)

Basically, there is no width/height of display objects in EaselJS, but you can change the actual drawing command any time. You can also change the scaleX/scaleY, and set the stroke to `ignoreScale`:

```
shape.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1, null, null, null, true); // 5th param
```

Further reading:

- http://blog.createjs.com/new-command-approach-to-easeljs-graphics/
- http://blog.createjs.com/update-width-height-in-easeljs/